# convert string to sql image type

Tags: c#, sql, image

I have c# app with sql database,in sql field type is image, but my c# app variable is string , how to store string var to image type in sql database?

```
parameters[10] = new OleDbParameter("@LONG_DESCRIPTION", sLongDes);
// sLongDes is string type, LONG_DESCRIPTION in sql is imag type
parameters[10].OleDbType = OleDbType.LongVarBinary;
```

this code is wrong.

Comment: In which manner is the code wrong?

Comment: Are you attempting to store the image as raw bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to convert the string into `Byte Array`

```
byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sLongDes); // supports other encoding
parameters[10] = new OleDbParameter("@LONG_DESCRIPTION", array);
parameters[10].OleDbType = OleDbType.LongVarBinary;
```